# php can't find syntax error in echo line

Tags: php, syntax

So I am getting the following parse error when this file loads:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), 
expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number 
(T_NUM_STRING)
```

I have tried everything to work out why and I narrowed it down to the

```
href=\"start.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'] ?>\"
```

section of the code. I am sure I left out a ' or " but unsure where as 
it all makes sense to me. Can anyone with a keener eye see where I am 
going wrong? Thank you.

My code:

```
<td>

<?php if($res['ndaSent'] == "No") {
echo "<span class=\"buttonTestDisabled\"> Start Test</span>";} 
else {
echo "<a class=\"buttonTest\" href=\"start.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'] 
?>\">Start Test</a> ";}
?>

</td>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use single quotes within echo lines?

Comment: Should be `echo '<a class="buttonTest" href="start.php?id='.$res['id'].'">Start Test</a>';`. You cannot echo inside a echo. And look at the quotes.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now. I didn't realize single quotes were accepted for echos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at that. You can't use echo command inside of an echo " " line. Try using ' inside and not \ may help you too from confusion.

```
<?php if($res['ndaSent'] == "No") {
echo "<span class='buttonTestDisabled'> Start Test</span>";

}else{

echo "<a class='buttonTest' href='start.php?id=".$res['id'].">Start Test</a>';}
?>

</td>
```

Comment: echo "<a class='buttonTest' href='start.php?id=".$res['id']."'>Start Test</a>";